# Why does /ɪ/ often sound like /ə/?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics, weak-vowel-merger

For example: if you listen to the pronunciation of "seminar" in [Oxford Learners Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/seminar), it sounds like an /ə/ to me.

BrE /ˈsemɪnɑː(r)

Comment: definitely, look for "weak vowel merger"

Comment: [In English, vowels in unstressed position tend to move to schwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa).

Answer (score 2):

To my ears, neither the British nor American speaker have reduced the vowel in the second syllable in *seminar* to a schwa. In the pronunciation of *[adequate](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/adequate?q=adequate)* on the same website, however, I hear the American speaker reducing the vowel in the second syllable to a schwa, while the British speaker even lengthens it a bit. The IPA symbol is identical for both.

Our ears have accents as well, and we often hear others pronounce words as we do even when they in fact do not. If your particular dialect is one where the [weak vowel merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_high_front_vowels?wprov=sfti1) has taken place, then the difference you hear may only seem like insignificant positional variants rather than distinct vowels.

Comment: If neither of them pronounced it as a schwa then what did they pronounce it as? Surely not an /ɪ/.

Comment: Sorry, but that's the vowel I heard.

Comment: It sounds very different to me from the /ɪ/ in "it". Does it sound different to you to? What is the reason? Weak vowel merger?

Comment: The vowels sound the same as here: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bin_1?q=bin though the American seems to pronounce it a tiny bit further back. If you compare _bit_, you hear the heavily aspirated _t_ move the vowel a bit toward the front for both. At least that's what I'm hearing. Maybe you start hearing schwa earlier than I do as the vowel moves back.

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/capital_1       what about the British pronounciation of Capital. Does it sound like ɪ?

Comment: I'm still hearing a garden variety short i.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76600/discussion-on-answer-by-karlg-why-does--often-sound-like-).

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603199/2085).